# How to solve redefinition of main in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to compile and link three files into an executable with a makefile, but seem to have redefined main or somehow goofed the compile/link process. The project is for a class, where the objective is to implement a linear feedback shift register, but we have to use a makefile.

Where have I redefined main? How do I alter my makefile to create my executable? I notice the error points to test.o as having redefined main, but I'm not sure why or how.

Error:

```
g++ -c main.cpp LFSR.cpp -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic
g++ -c test.cpp -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic
g++ main.o LFSR.o test.o -o ps2a -lboost_unit_test_framework
test.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xa3): multiple definition of `main'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'ps2a' failed
make: *** [ps2a] Error 1
```

My makefile:

```
all: ps2a

ps2a: main.o LFSR.o test.o
     g++ main.o LFSR.o test.o -o ps2a -lboost_unit_test_framework

LFSR.o: LFSR.cpp LFSR.hpp
     g++ -c LFSR.cpp -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic

main.o: main.cpp LFSR.hpp
    g++ -c main.cpp LFSR.cpp -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic

test.o: test.cpp
    g++ -c test.cpp -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic

clean:
    rm *.o ps2a
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "LFSR.hpp"

int main(){
}
```

LFSR.hpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class LFSR{
public:
    LFSR(std::string, int);
    int step();
    int generate(int k);
private:
    std::string bitString;
    int tapPos;
};
```

LFSR.cpp:

```
#include "LFSR.hpp"

void makeBitStringValid(std::string& str);

LFSR::LFSR(std::string str, int t){
}

int LFSR::step(){
    return 0;
}

int LFSR::generate(int k){
    return 0;
}

void makeBitStringValid(std::string& str){
}
```

test.cpp (Note, this is given by the instructor-- I'm not entirely sure how it works yet)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "LFSR.hpp"

#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Main
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(fiveBitsTapAtTwo) {

  LFSR l("00111", 2);
  BOOST_REQUIRE(l.step() == 1);
  BOOST_REQUIRE(l.step() == 1);
  BOOST_REQUIRE(l.step() == 0);
  BOOST_REQUIRE(l.step() == 0);
  BOOST_REQUIRE(l.step() == 0);
  BOOST_REQUIRE(l.step() == 1);
  BOOST_REQUIRE(l.step() == 1);
  BOOST_REQUIRE(l.step() == 0);

  LFSR l2("00111", 2);
  BOOST_REQUIRE(l2.generate(8) == 198);
}
```

Comment: Don't write a main.cpp.

Comment: Why shouldn't I write main.cpp?

Comment: Because you already have a main function?

Comment: Because you have main defined twice. It's already in test.cpp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not provide own `main` because The Boost Unit Test Framework already provides one in your `test.cpp` with the lines:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Main
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

> ### [Dynamic library variant of the UTF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-runners.html)
>
> Unlike the static library variant function main() can't reside in the
>   dynamic library body. Instead this variant supplies default function
>   main() implementation as part of the header `boost/test/unit_test.hpp`
>   to be generated as part of your test file body. The function main() is
>   generated only if either the BOOST_TEST_MAIN or the BOOST_TEST_MODULE
>   flags are defined during a test module compilation. For single-file
>   test module flags can be defined either in a test module's makefile or
>   before the header `boost/test/unit_test.hpp` inclusion. For a multi-file
>   test module flags can't be defined in makefile and have to be defined
>   in only one of the test files to avoid duplicate copies of the
>   function main().